# Architecting a system for reminder emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, cron, delayed-job

I'm building a reservation system in Rails 4.2 where I need to send a set of emails to users at predefined intervals (for example that they have an upcoming reservation, feedback after it's done, a link to change/cancel an existing reservation, etc.). I've looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273116/best-way-to-dynamically-schedule-reminder-email-anything-better-than-cron) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022650/sending-dynamic-email-reminders-in-ruby-on-rails?rq=1), but I'm trying to decide between the approaches.

I see two main ways of building this system out.

1. Using a queue system like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). Whenever someone makes a reservation, we queue up all the emails for the correct time when they should be sent.

   Pro: One queue for all emails. Automatic retry logic.

   Con: Thousands of emails will eventually get queued in the system. Need to dequeue whenever someone cancels a reservation (dependent: destroy emails related to it might be pretty easy). Somewhat more complex logic around what time we need the emails to go out.
2. `cron` + `rake` task that runs at some predefined interval (hourly? every fifteen minutes?) and checks for the emails that need to go out. It runs a query like "Find all reservations that are three days from now", and then sends out all emails.

   Pro: Put everything into application logic, reduce the amount of state we need to keep track of.

   Con: Need to keep track of which emails have been sent, which is conceptually similar to whatever jobs table we already have created above.

Comment: I used the second approach(because I never thought of the first approach :P), somehow I feel like the second approach is safer and easier to manage. Relying on delayed job is somehow not so safe as job process might drop and more complex logic as what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Second approach is better (use heroku scheduler if on heroku), queues are more for "run as soon as possible" than "run at this particular datetime"

Answer (score 0):

The one good advantage of 1) using delayed_job (or Sidekiq) is that you could update the schedule of a job (or a recurring job) from the site dynamically.

You can provide a page in your site to update recurring jobs. Now, delayed_job doesn't really allow recurring jobs by default. There are add-on gems that could be of interest though [delayed_job_recurring](https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring) or [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler). If compute power is not a problem, I would always prefer an actual job processor rather than cron because it is just more manageable for me.